# Read from ajax response(result)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have write a ajax query to get some data in database. but I am facing difficulties when turn result to jquery.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: base + homepage + '/getDaysbyAjent',
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        data : {"ajent" : ajent_id},
        dataType: "json",

        success: function(data) {
            if(data){
                    alert(data);
            }

        }
    });
```

---

```
    public function getDaysbyAjent(){
        $ajentID = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('ajent_id'));
        $agentBooking = $this->BookingModel->getBookingForAjent($ajentID);
        echo json_encode($agentBooking);
    }
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $res = $this->db->where('agentId', $ajentID)->get('bookingtbl')->result();
    foreach($res as $booking) {
        $booking_arr_date[$i] = $booking->date;
        $booking_arr_time[$i] = $booking->timing;
        $i++;
    }
 
$booking_arr['dates'] = $booking_arr_date;
$booking_arr['times'] = $booking_arr_time;
return $booking_arr;
```

I have used alert(JSON.parse(data)); but Only show me "Object", Can Someone Please tell me how to do this. I need to loop through all dates and all times arrays separately.

Comment: Tip: don't use `async: false`. Synchronous AJAX requests are deprecated because they lock up the browser UI while the request is in progress, causing a poor user experience. They're also unnecessary. You're handling the AJAX response correctly via the `success` callback, so you don't need it to be synchronous.

Comment: Please show an example of the data returned and what you expect it to change into - `return $booking_arr;` does not in itself return JSON - for that you need json_encode

Comment: `I have used alert(JSON.parse(data)); but Only show me "Object"`...that'll be because `data` is an object or array. Javascript has no way of knowing how you want that to be displayed visually. You'll need to access the properties of the object individually to display or process them. We don't know what you want to do with the data. Background reading: https://www.google.com/search?q=js+produces+object+object

Comment: Instead of `alert(data);` do `console.log(data);` , what is the result?

Answer (score 0):

Data is an object or array format that's why it shows an object in the alert box. try console.log and view the result in the browser console

```
console.log(data);
```